# @use is coming soon, but it's not supported in this version of Dart Sass

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I am running `ng serve` with an Angular cli project which includes Sass. I have been using `@import` and `@include` with no problem, when I added `@use`, the terminal throws:

> @use is coming soon, but it's not supported in this version of Dart
>   Sass.

My package.json uses `"sass": "1.25.0"`, which according to the official documentation, `@use` has been supported since 1.23.

Is there something I'm missing?

UPDATE: I see that Angular lists Sass as a dependency in package-lock.json but with an older version. How can I make it to match the package.json version? I tried changed manually, `run npm i --save` but then package-lock.json reverts to the older version.

UPDATE 2 - Feb 2020: Even both package-lock.json and package.json show that use a 1.25.0 version of Sass, still can't use `@use`

Comment: Try deleting your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` directory and run an `npm install` again

Comment: that doesn't work. the package-lock.json lists an older version of sass.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at using package [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) in the npm docs
Another option is using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Add the following to your package.json

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "sass": "1.57.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `@use`, then go to package.json and update dart-sass

```json
{
    "dart-sass": "^1.25.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### May 2023 update,

With the latest version of Angular (15+ and maybe lower),

you don't need to import anymore the `sass` package and `@use` is working as expected.

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried with caret (^)?

Like:

```
 "sass" : "^1.25.0"
```