# Sass error on Angular update "@use is coming soon, but it's not supported in this version of Dart Sass"

Tags: angular, sass

I received an error message during an update of a project from Angular v7 to v8.

```
@use is coming soon, but it's not supported in this version of Dart Sass
```

- I'm following the steps of [Angular update instructions from 7.2 to 8.2](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=7.2-8.2), section "Before Updating" is done. The error appears in the first steps of the "During the Update" section.
- The project previously used `node-sass`, ng8 now uses `sass` as part of the migration.
- The package `@angular-devkit/build-angular` forces `sass@1.22.9`, but I'm reading `@use` isn't available until `sass@1.23.0`.
- `@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.900.0` is the first version with sass newer than 1.22.9, but I'm assuming I should use it when upgrading ng from 8 to 9, and I'm not there yet.
- I have not an implicit reference to sass in my `package.json`, it's implied from the use of the base package `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. I do use sass files for the component styles.

I'm stuck here because I wish to build, run and review the app before continuing the upgrade process to ng 9. I didn't know what I'm missing here.

> Btw I think this is not the same scenario of the **unanswered** question [60030890](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030890/use-is-coming-soon-but-its-not-supported-in-this-version-of-dart-sass?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C645.3954) and probably doesn't get solved the same way.

Comment: Hi, Have you able to get a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. My upgrade tasks on this particular project were paused for a long time. If I retake later I'll post here any solution or workaround.